# How to parse generic text query into dictionary - Python

Tags: python, django, text

I'm trying to parse generic text query that can look as the following in Python:

```
first_name:Jon last_name:"Doe" address:"1st X street, Y, California"
```

to:

```py
{
 "first_name":"Jon",
 "last_name":"Doe",
 "address":"1st X street, Y, California"
}
```

Any ideas how to do it while being able to properly parse text between quotes and spaces?

Answer (score 0):

str.split() is what your looking for here, it separates parts of a string into a list based on the delimiter you give it with empty space as a default
**ex:**

```
string = 'first_name:Jon last_name:"Doe" address:"1st X street, Y, California"'

dictionary={}

list_of_strings = string.split()

for i, string in enumerate(list_of_strings):
    list_of_strings[i] = string.split(':')

for lst  in list_of_strings:
    dictionary[lst[0]] = lst[1]
```

Comment: Looks great, the problem is that the address is being splitted into 5 items. Any ideas how to overcome it?

`>>> s = 'first_name:Jon last_name:"Doe" address:"1st X street, Y, California"'`

`>>> s.split()`

`['first_name:Jon', 'last_name:"Doe"', 'address:"1st', 'X', 'street,', 'Y,', 'California"']`

Comment: trying to modify this t use regex instead, but I cant seem to find a good pattern to find